# Why does JQuery only toggle the paragraphs and the first input field but not the second one?

Tags: jquery

The paragraph is supposed to be a description for the input next to it. In reality only the paragraph is affected by the toggle.

I'm new to jQuery so I might be missing something obvious.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ausfallcheck").change(function() {
    $("#ausfall").toggle();
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p hidden>Ausfall Beginn:<p> 
    <br />
    <input type="datetime-local" name="ausfall-anfang" id="ausfall" hidden required onchange="check_time_ausfall()" />
    <br />
<p hidden>Ausfall Ende:</p>   
    <br />
    <input type="datetime-local" name="ausfall-ende" id="ausfall" hidden required onchange="check_time_ausfall()"/>
    <br />
```

EDIT:
Edited the question, since it was not possible to spot the error in it. All other answers reference the original, badly constructed, question!

Comment: There is no `#ausfallcheck` element in your code. Could you please edit the question to give a much clearer example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ausfallcheck is the checkbox. I only wanted to include the important bits to not confuse somebody. The html code is in between php code.

Comment: It would have helped to see exactly where the checkbox is in the logic in case it was part of the problem. I've added an answer for you below.

Comment: Thank for the advise. I will try to format everything better next time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to spot the problem in the question I provided.

I used the same ID multiple times resulting in the JQuery script to only toggle the first input and not the second one with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

You are having another child `<p>` tag inside the parent paragraph. That one is not initially hidden and affect the input visibility when toggled.

Comment: The problem was that I misunderstood the id attribute and had two inputs with id=ausfall. When I tried to manipulate #ausfall it only toggled the first input field.

Comment: It was't possible to spot this in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you have two `p` elements. One starts hidden, the other visible although hidden by its parent. As such, when you `toggle()` those elements the outer one become visible and the inner invisible.

To fix this provide the boolean `checked` property of the checkbox to both `p` elements so that their states align:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ausfallcheck").change(function() {
    $("#ausfall").toggle(this.checked);
    $("p").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="ausfallcheck" />
<p hidden>Ausfall Beginn:
  <p> 
    <br />
    <input type="datetime-local" name="ausfall-anfang" id="ausfall" hidden required onchange="check_time_ausfall()" />
    <br />
  </p>
</p>
```

Alternatively you could amend the `p` selector to only target the outer element.

Also note the use of the `change` event over `click` here, which is preferred on radio and checkbox inputs for accessibility reasons.

Comment: ..or add an ID to the paragraph that should be toggled and only toggle that ID.

Comment: @jjhavokk indeed, see my last paragraph in the answer.

Comment: I initially planned `<p>Ausfall Beginn</p>` etc.. It was just a simple typo. Thanks very much though!

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys again but it might not be the typo. Even how it is in my question doesn't work. (with `<p>`and`</p>`). It now only shows the first input together with all the paragraphs

Comment: Without seeing the actual problem reproduced it's impossible to tell you what the issue is. As you can see from the above example, though, if you have the HTML correct it should work. Try checking the console for errors

Comment: The problem was that I misunderstood the id attribute and had two inputs with id=ausfall. When I tried to manipulate #ausfall it only toggled the first input field.

Comment: It was't possible to spot this in my original question.

Comment: Which is the reason my first comment on the question asked for more detail, but I'm glad you got it working at least